# BinaryReader ReadInt32() returns a number that is too big

Tags: binaryreader

It read from a file that is .eml file less than 2k.
  guess what?  msgCount is 1717924456    why ReadInt32 return so much big?

```
         protected void Load( Stream msgStream )
    {
        if( msgStream == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "messageStream" );
        BinaryReader bsr = new BinaryReader( msgStream );
        MailAddress  = bsr.ReadString();
        MailUser     = bsr.ReadString();
        MailServer   = bsr.ReadString();
        UseSsl       = bsr.ReadBoolean();
        MailPort     = bsr.ReadInt32();
        MailPassword = bsr.ReadString();
        int i, msgCount = bsr.ReadInt32();
        for( i = 0; i < msgCount; i++ )
        {
            int msgLen = bsr.ReadInt32();
            MessageExt msg = new MessageExt( bsr.ReadBytes( msgLen ) );
            msg.RecvTime = DateTime.FromBinary( bsr.ReadInt64() );
```

this code work before, but now seem odd, it seem i changed some setting that lead to such exception?

Answer (score 2):

1717924456 == 0x66657268 which looks suspiciously like ASCII hex codes for English characters.

Assuming a little-endian processor, it corresponds to the string "href" (0x68, 0x72, 0x65, 0x66). So you are likely reading from the wrong address (i.e. from the body of the message).

Use a hex editor to manually verify the file's contents and ensure that it isn't corrupt.

Comment: you are smart. thanks. here is compelte code, it seem it corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

`ReadInt32` [reads a 32-bit signed integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the file and returns that. It *sounds* like you expect it to return the number of bytes read (based on your concern that the file is only 2K long) - that's not what it does.

If the first four octets of the file are some massively large 32-bit signed number, that's what you'll see. If you're expecting to see a smaller number (because you think the first four bytes actually *contain* the message count), see below.

---

Interestingly enough, the value you're getting is what I'd expect to see in a textual file format, though not *necessarily* an RFC822-compliant email file.

The number `1,717,924,456` is hexadecimal `0x66657268`, which translates to the ASCII characters `ferh`.

Reversed (due to the endianness of the platform), that's `href` which should be instantly familiar to the hordes of web-savvy bods out there. I'd suggest opening up the file in your favourite text editor and looking to see what the first four characters are.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> hex(1717924456)
'0x66657268'
>>> '\x66\x65\x72\x68'
'ferh'
```

You have somehow managed to completely blow past any binary header and are now into the data. Review your previous steps to verify that they are operating correctly.